# Excel 2013 VBA Connection String Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm having an issue with my connection string to connect an excel document to an access database.

A 'Type Mismatch' error appears when i run this. But it only affects excel 2013, excel 365 works fine.

I've narrowed the issue down to the data source, as if i shorten the drive by moving the database up some levels, or setting a drive path, then it also works fine. However i cannot move the database or set a drive path as a fix.

The Datasource path is only 154 characters.

```
Dim strTable As String, strDrive As String, strDriTab As String
Dim rngDes As Range


If .Range("b7").Value = "" Then
.Range("b4").Value = rngTbl.Value
.Range("b4").Font.Bold = True
.Range("b4").Font.Size = 12
Set rngDes = .Range("b7")
Else
Dim rngFormat As Range
Set rngFormat = .Range("b60000").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)
rngFormat = rngTbl.Value
rngFormat.Font.Bold = True
rngFormat.Font.Size = 12
Set rngDes = .Range("b60000").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)
End If

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider:=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password:="""";User ID:=Admin;Data Source:=" & strDrive & strTable & ";Mode:=ReadWrite;Extended Properties" _
    , _
    ":="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path:="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password:=""*******"";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type:=5;Jet OLEDB:Dat" _
    , _
    "abase Locking Mode:=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops:=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions:=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password:=""""" _
    , _
    ";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database:=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database:=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact:=False;Jet OLEDB:" _
    , "Compact Without Replica Repair:=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP:=False"), Destination:= _
    rngDes)

    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = sql
    .Name = rngDes.Address
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceDataFile = strDrive & strTable
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't appear to have any values in `strDrive` or `strTable`. I'd also suggest you get rid of the `Array()` and just pass the `Connection` argument as one string.

Comment: Hi, I purposely avoided adding those values for security reasons. But they are correct. I've tried without using Array and it seems to work. I'm testing a bit more and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Hi Rory, That worked, i cant believe it was that easy. Please add your suggestion as an answer, and i will mark it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array()` function is limited to 255 characters for each element, which may be causing your problem depending on the length of the `strDrive` and `strTable` arguments. Fortunately, it's unnecessary here - you should just pass the `Connection` argument as a simple String value:

```
Connection:="OLEDB;Provider:=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password:="""";User ID:=Admin;Data Source:=" & strDrive & strTable & ";Mode:=ReadWrite;Extended Properties:="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path:="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password:=""*******"";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type:=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode:=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops:=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions:=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password:="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database:=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database:=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact:=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair:=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP:=False"
```